# My Herokuapp is inaccessible from custom domain name

Tags: domains, dns

I have a Heroku app that is located at myapp.herokuapp.com. I have mapped a domain name to this app, using the A properties. I followed the instructions on Heroku's website to the letter, and it worked for a few days. Now when I try to access the site from the custom domain, it's timing out!

On Chrome, I am getting "Oops! Google Chrome could not find that page!" message.

I tried pinging the name as well, but I got this error:

> ping: cannot resolve yourhostname.org: Unknown host

The app itself is working and I don't see any error messages from Heroku. Or from new Relic. What's going on here?

Also tried running `host` and this was the error message:

> ;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it was the GoDaddy outage of 2012. Scary times.